# PHP does not recognize plugin_url function

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to find the plugin and webcontent URL addresses but the php does not recognize the functions

```
  Call to undefined function plugins_url()
  Call to undefined function content_url()


  $wp_plugin_url = plugins_url();
  $wp_content_url = content_url();
  echo $wp_plugin_url;
```

Answer (score 0):

From where are you calling this function? [plugins_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) is a function defined in wordpress. you must link your file  to wordpress before using it.

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );  
require('wp-blog-header.php'); #modify to match path of that file on your server

$wp_plugin_url = plugins_url();
$wp_content_url = content_url();
```

Comment: I have a login page and I can use it on that page but when I redirect to the new page I cant use it in my new page. I am wondering how is it recognizable on the first page and not on the second one?

Comment: when the user is logged in will be redirected to the new page, when I try to find the plugin_url in the second page it does not recognize it.

Comment: what is that second page where the user is redirected?

Comment: I used your code but it does not show anything, just a blank page

Comment: You should continue writing your codes. if you didn't get any errors, it means it's working.

Comment: Try using the constant `WP_PLUGIN_URL`

Comment: the problem is not recognizing the functions not the define

Comment: try using `if(function_exists('plugins_url'))`